# What is the error in Manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.piggybank">

<activity
    android:name="c.b.a.A"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation"
    android:exported="false"
    android:screenOrientation="behind"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />

<activity
    android:name="c.b.a.B"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

<!-- 允许联网 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- 获取wifi网络状态的信息 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<!-- 保持CPU 运转，屏幕和键盘灯有可能是关闭的,用于文件上传和下载 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- 获取sd卡写的权限，用于文件上传和下载 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- 允许读取手机状态 用于创建BmobInstallation -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- android:hardwareAccelerated="false"66666 -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".EditWishMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".personalMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".registMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".BankMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PayMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.WishFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.SuccessFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.DiscoverFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.MeFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.jingxuan_fragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.Mytidings_fragment" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity android:name=".EditDotaiMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".QianBaoMainActivity"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

When I build the apk, it keeps making this error,but I cannot find the reason...I don't think I put an activity in an activity, but the error is there...

> > Error:(5) Error: The  element must be a direct child of the
> >      element [WrongManifestParent]  Error:(12) Error: The  element must be a direct child of the  element
> >     [WrongManifestParent]

Comment: where is the package info?

Comment: Add Activity in application tag in your manifest:

Comment: Formatting and appropriate title

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the activities inside your Apllication tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.piggybank">


<!-- 允许联网 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- 获取GSM（2g）、WCDMA（联通3g）等网络状态的信息 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- 获取wifi网络状态的信息 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<!-- 保持CPU 运转，屏幕和键盘灯有可能是关闭的,用于文件上传和下载 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- 获取sd卡写的权限，用于文件上传和下载 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- 允许读取手机状态 用于创建BmobInstallation -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- android:hardwareAccelerated="false"66666 -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="c.b.a.A"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation"
    android:exported="false"
    android:screenOrientation="behind"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />

    <activity
    android:name="c.b.a.B"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".EditWishMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".personalMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".registMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".BankMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PayMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.WishFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.SuccessFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.DiscoverFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.MeFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.jingxuan_fragment" />
    <activity android:name=".fragment.Mytidings_fragment" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity android:name=".EditDotaiMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".QianBaoMainActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

also please refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- you have to declare `activity` inside `application` like this.
- I think you have to close the tag of `</manifest>`

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest 
     xmlns :android="http://schemas.android.co
    m /apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.piggybank">



 <!-- 允许联网 -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <!-- 获取GSM（2g）、WCDMA（联通3g）等网络状态的信息 -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <!-- 获取wifi网络状态的信息 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
     <!-- 保持CPU 运转，屏幕和键盘灯有可能是关闭的,用于文件上传和下载 -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
      <!-- 获取sd卡写的权限，用于文件上传和下载 -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <!-- 允许读取手机状态 用于创建BmobInstallation -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


   <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<!-- android:hardwareAccelerated="false"66666 -->
<activity android:name=".MainActivity1">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
<activity android:name=".EditWishMainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".personalMainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".registMainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".BankMainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".PayMainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".fragment.WishFragment" />
<activity android:name=".fragment.SuccessFragment" />
<activity android:name=".fragment.DiscoverFragment" />
<activity android:name=".fragment.MeFragment" />
<activity android:name=".fragment.jingxuan_fragment" />
<activity android:name=".fragment.Mytidings_fragment" />

<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>

<activity android:name=".EditDotaiMainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".QianBaoMainActivity">.      </activity>
  <activity
android:name="c.b.a.A"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation"
android:exported="false"
android:screenOrientation="behind"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />

   <activity
android:name="c.b.a.B"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
   </application>
    </manifest>
```